# Django prefetch_related GenericForeignKey with multiple content types

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm using [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream) to display a list of recent events. For the sake of example these could be someone commenting or someone editing an article. I.e. the GenericForeignKey `action_object` could reference a `Comment` or an `Article`. I'd like to display a link to whatever the `action_object` is too:

```
<a href="{{ action.action_object.get_absolute_url }}">
{{ action.action_object }}
</a>
```

The problem is this causes queries for every single item, particularly as `Comment.get_absolute_url` requires the comment's `article`, which has not been fetched yet, and `Article.__unicode__` requires its `revision.content`, which also hasn't been fetched.

`django-activity-stream` already calls [`prefetch_related('action_object')`](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/0867875cb8d9c20c7c429382592bc981dad74a91/actstream/gfk.py#L43) automatically ([related discussion](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/issues/34#issuecomment-2493139)).
This appears to be working as testing with `{{ action.action_object.id }}` results in a single query per `action_object_content_type`, despite [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) saying:

> It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey, however, it must be restricted to a homogeneous set of results. For example, prefetching objects referenced by a GenericForeignKey is only supported if the query is restricted to one ContentType.

And there is more than one content type. However in my use case above I need extra `prefetch_related` calls, for example:

```
query = query.prefetch_related('action_object__article`, `action_object__revision`)
```

But this complains because `Article`s don't have an `__article` (and would probably complain about `Comment`s not having a `__revision` too if it got that far). I'm assuming this is what the docs are really referring to. So I thought I'd try this:

```
comments = query._clone().filter(action_object_content_type=comment_ctype).prefetch_related('action_object__article')
articles = query._clone().filter(action_object_content_type=article_ctype).prefetch_related('action_object__revision')
query = comments | articles
```

But the results are always empty. I guess querysets only support a single `prefetch_related` list and can't be joined like that.

I like a single queryset to return because further filtering is done later in the code which this part doesn't know about. Although once the queryset is finally evaluated I want to be able to have django fetch everything needed to render the events.

Is there another way?

I had a look at [`Prefetch` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) but I don't think they offer any help in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be found in `django-notify-x` which is derived from `django-notifications` which, in turn, is derived from `django-activity-stream`. It makes use of a "django snippet" linked in the copied text below.

https://github.com/v1k45/django-notify-x/pull/19

> Using a snippet from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2492/,
>   prefetch generic relations to reduce the number of queries.
>
> Currently, we trigger one additional query for each generic relation
>   for each record, with this code, we reduce to one additional query for
>   each generic relation for each type of generic relation used.
>
> If all your notifications are related to a Badges model, only one
>   aditional query will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.10 and 1.11, I am using the snippet above modified as below (just in case you are not using django-activity-stream):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import fields as generic


def get_field_by_name(meta, fname):
    return [f for f in meta.get_fields() if f.name == fname]


def prefetch_relations(weak_queryset):
    weak_queryset = weak_queryset.select_related()

    # reverse model's generic foreign keys into a dict:
    # { 'field_name': generic.GenericForeignKey instance, ... }
    gfks = {}
    for name, gfk in weak_queryset.model.__dict__.items():
        if not isinstance(gfk, generic.GenericForeignKey):
            continue
        gfks[name] = gfk

    data = {}
    for weak_model in weak_queryset:
        for gfk_name, gfk_field in gfks.items():
            related_content_type_id = getattr(weak_model, get_field_by_name(gfk_field.model._meta, gfk_field.ct_field)[
                0].get_attname())
            if not related_content_type_id:
                continue
            related_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(related_content_type_id)
            related_object_id = int(getattr(weak_model, gfk_field.fk_field))

            if related_content_type not in data.keys():
                data[related_content_type] = []
            data[related_content_type].append(related_object_id)

    for content_type, object_ids in data.items():
        model_class = content_type.model_class()
        models = prefetch_relations(model_class.objects.filter(pk__in=object_ids))
        for model in models:
            for weak_model in weak_queryset:
                for gfk_name, gfk_field in gfks.items():
                    related_content_type_id = getattr(weak_model,
                                                      get_field_by_name(gfk_field.model._meta, gfk_field.ct_field)[
                                                          0].get_attname())
                    if not related_content_type_id:
                        continue
                    related_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(related_content_type_id)
                    related_object_id = int(getattr(weak_model, gfk_field.fk_field))

                    if related_object_id != model.pk:
                        continue
                    if related_content_type != content_type:
                        continue

                    setattr(weak_model, gfk_name, model)

    return weak_queryset
```

This is giving me the intended results.

EDIT:

To use it, you simply call prefetch_relations, with your QuerySet as the argument.

For example, instead of:

```
my_objects = MyModel.objects.all()
```

you can do this:

```
my_objects = prefetch_relations(MyModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: Hello! Can you add comment what exactly your code doing? What I need to modify if I want to use this code? Lets say I have model `Article`. I need to see last events which was in that modal. Like edit/create, someone add comment.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek My code is almost the same as the code provided in the accepted answer. But I modified it to work with Django 1.11. This is used by simply passing your queryset to the prefetch_relations method as an argument. See the edit for an example.

Comment: In my case I've used the code as is, it is supposed to be generic.

Comment: So as I understand its improvement to `django-notify-x` app. I use Django 1.10. So I think your code will be helpfull for me. I am steal dont undertand one think. This line `my_objects = prefetch_relations(MyModel.objects.all())` will show last events which was in MyModal? I am right?

Comment: If you get the events using: `Event.objects.all()`, then `prefetch_relations(Event.objects.all())` will give you your events with the prefetched relations.